# Android App: page stopped working

Tags: java, php, android, multithreading

I am developing a simple Android app and am getting a 'App stopped working' error.

The error seems to happen when I exit my `preOnExecute` method but if I comment that out the app falls over on next code piece anyway.

Test: Open screen/activity, there are 5 pre filled textboxes and a button. If I click the button the code hits a class that opens a dialog in 'OnPreExecute' and it fails on execiting this method.

Its probably something to do with the background thread not liking whats happening on UI but i dont know.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

See below for code

```
package android22.app.namespace;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android22.voter.namespace.appSubmitAnswerActivity.GetQuestionDetails;
import android22.voter.namespace.appSubmitAnswerActivity.SaveAnswerDetails;

public class appCreateQuestionActivity extends Activity  {

    //controls

       EditText editTextTitle;
       EditText editTextQuestionString;
       EditText editTextA1;
       EditText editTextA2;
       EditText editTextA3;
       EditText editTextA4;
       EditText editTextA5;
       Button buttonSubmitQuestion;



       // Progress Dialog 
       private ProgressDialog qDialog; 

       // JSON parser class 
       JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 

       // single question url 
       private static final String url_insert_question_details = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/voter/Voter_Db_CreateNewQuestion.php"; 


       // JSON Node names
       private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
       private static final String TAG_QUESTION = "question";
       private static final String TAG_QID = "Qid";
       private static final String TAG_TITLE = "Title";
       private static final String TAG_QUESTIONSTRING = "QuestionString";
       private static final String TAG_A1 = "A1";
       private static final String TAG_A2 = "A2";
       private static final String TAG_A3 = "A3";
       private static final String TAG_A4 = "A4";
       private static final String TAG_A5 = "A5";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createquestion);

        // save button 
        buttonSubmitQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate); 
        /*Set Control Listeners */

        buttonSubmitQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

           @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {           

                // starting background task to update question 
              new SaveQuestionDetails().execute();
            } 
        }); 



    }

    class SaveQuestionDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

           /**
            * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
            * */
           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();
               qDialog = new ProgressDialog(VoterCreateQuestionActivity.this);
               qDialog.setMessage("Saving ...");
               qDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
               qDialog.setCancelable(true);
               qDialog.show();  
           }

           /**
            * Saving question
            * */
           protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

               String Title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
               String Question = editTextQuestionString.getText().toString();
               String A1 = editTextA1.getText().toString();
               String A2 = editTextA2.getText().toString();
               String A3 = editTextA3.getText().toString();
               String A4 = editTextA4.getText().toString();
               String A5 = editTextA5.getText().toString();


               // Building Parameters
               List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_QID, "1"));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TITLE, Title));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_QUESTION, Question));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_A1, A1));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_A2, A2));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_A3, A3));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_A4, A4));
               params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_A5, A5));


               // sending modified data through http request
               // Notice that update question url accepts POST method
               JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_question_details,
                       "POST", params);

               // check json success tag
               try {
                   int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                   if (success == 1) {
                       // successfully updated
                       Intent i = getIntent();
                       // send result code 100 to notify about question update
                       setResult(100, i);
                       finish();
                   } else {
                       // failed to update question
                   }
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               return null;
           }

           /**
            * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
            * **/
           protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
               // dismiss the dialog once question updated
               qDialog.dismiss();
           }
       }
}
```

I get the following LogCat

```
09-20 16:03:15.703: D/gralloc_goldfish(658): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-20 16:20:39.298: W/dalvikvm(658): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android22.voter.namespace.AppCreateQuestionActivity$SaveQuestionDetails.doInBackground(VoterCreateQuestionActivity.java:109)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android22.voter.namespace.AppCreateQuestionActivity$SaveQuestionDetails.doInBackground(VoterCreateQuestionActivity.java:1)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  ... 4 more
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658): Activity android22.voter.namespace.AppCreateQuestionActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@416e3798 that was originally added here
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity android22.voter.namespace.AppCreateQuestionActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@416e3798 that was originally added here
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android22.voter.namespace.AppCreateQuestionActivity$SaveQuestionDetails.onPreExecute(VoterCreateQuestionActivity.java:101)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android22.voter.namespace.VoterCreateQuestionActivity$1.onClick(AppCreateQuestionActivity.java:81)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-20 16:20:41.493: E/WindowManager(658):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace for the crash?

Comment: Is the log cat ok or do you want something else??

Comment: you have a nullpointerexception in your doInBackground(String... args) method, just run a debug on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by line 109:

```
String Title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
```

And it's a NullPointerException. Most likely, it's caused by the fact that class member variable `editTextTitle` is not initialized anywhere. You typically initialize those in your `onCreate()`, some time after `setContentView()`, by calling `findViewById()` with the relevant control ID.

That said, questions of the type "here's a large chunk of code, please debug for me" are frowned upon here at StackOverflow. You could've easily caught the error by placing a breakpoint inside the AsyncTask methods and stepping through each of them. That, or carefully reading the exception trace in the LogCat.

EDIT: the following lines in the LogCat are relevant:

```
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android22.voter.namespace.AppCreateQuestionActivity$SaveQuestionDetails.doInBackground(VoterCreateQuestionActivity.java:109)
```

The line number is right there. The exception was caught and rethrown a few times - that's typical. But to find the ultimate cause, you look for your code in the stack trace.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i couldnt see where it said null pointer exeption and as the code seemed to error out no matter what i did with preexecute i figured id put the whole thing up. what tells you its null pointer at line 109?

Comment: Your stacktrace shows that information:

    09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 16:20:39.463: E/AndroidRuntime(658):  at android22.voter.namespace.AppCreateQuestionActivity$SaveQuestionDetails.doInBackground(VoterCreateQuestionActivity.java:109)

Comment: Thanks a mil Seva. I have to do this when im a little more awake!